# Getting records which have only 1 matching row in the joined table?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following tables:

```
Persons  
|id   |firstname|lastname|  
|-----|---------|--------|  
|1    |John     |Doe     |  
|2    |Jim      |Smith   |  
|3    |Jane     |Boggard |  
|4    |Joe      |Dash    |  

Licences
|p_id |licence|
|-----|-------|
|1    |car    |
|1    |bike   |
|2    |car    |
|3    |car    |
|3    |bike   |
|1    |plane  |
|4    |bike   |
```

How can I get the persons who have only 1 associated row in the licences table and which the value is "car" ?  (in our case: Jim Smith)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question is pretty easy (getting a person with only 1 associated row in the `licenses` table). You just do a `GROUP BY`, and then `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`:

```
select
    persons.id
  ,persons.firstname
  ,Persons.lastname
from Persons
    inner join Licenses on
        Licenses.p_id = Persons.`id`
group by
    persons.id
    ,persons.firstname
    ,persons.lastname
having 
  count(*) = 1
```

The second part of your question is a little tricker: For the people with only 1 license, which have a car license. To do this, you can apply the filter to the `HAVING` clause, so it's applied after the `group by`. For example (note the new last line):

```
select
    persons.id
  ,persons.firstname
  ,Persons.lastname
from Persons
    inner join Licenses on
        Licenses.p_id = Persons.`id`
group by
    persons.id
    ,persons.firstname
    ,persons.lastname
having 
  count(*) = 1
  and min(licenses.licence) = 'car'
```

You're using the `MIN` function because you generally need to apply aggregate functions in the HAVING clause. However, since you already know that all these people only have 1 license, the `MIN` doesn't really make a difference (you could even use `MAX` with the same results).

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems to work as expected.
However I'd need an even more accurate query. 
Let's say I have a extra "year" column in the Licenses table. 
Is it possible to get the persons who have only 1 associated row in the licences table and which the licence value is "car" AND the year value is 2011 (for example) ?

Comment: Do I have to just add AND min(licenses.year) = '2011' or is it much tricker thant that ?

Comment: It depends on your logic: If you still want to only look at people with 1 license (where the license type is "car" and the year is "2011"), then you should be good adding that to the `HAVING` clause. However, if your logic is different (e.g. only people with 1 license in 2011, where that license type is "car"), then the query will have to be modified more extensively.

Answer (score 0):

This should help to illustrate the process...

```
SELECT p.*, SUM(l.licence = 'car') cars, COUNT(*) total
  FROM persons p
  JOIN licences l
    ON l.p_id = p.id
 GROUP
    BY p.id;
   +----+-----------+----------+------+-------+
   | id | firstname | lastname | cars | total |
   +----+-----------+----------+------+-------+
   |  1 | John      | Doe      |    1 |     3 |
   |  2 | Jim       | Smith    |    1 |     1 |
   |  3 | Jane      | Boggard  |    1 |     2 |
   |  4 | Joe       | Dash     |    0 |     1 |
   +----+-----------+----------+------+-------+
```